# How to get list of latest event per Id and month based on date interval?

Tags: date, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I have a table registering different event dates for unique identifiers - one row for each Id-event-date combination.
Each unique identifier can have multiple dates, according to the number of events happening to that Id. There are no two events occurring on the same date for individual Ids.

First, I wanted to identify the unique Ids for which the latest event has occurred for more than 7 days to current date. This is my working approach:

```
WITH latest_event AS
(
SELECT Id,
       date,
       event,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY date DESC) AS row_number
  FROM `table`
),

SELECT Id,
       date,
       event,
  FROM latest_stage 
 WHERE row_number = 1
   AND DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),date, DAY) > 7
 ORDER BY date
```

Now I would like to obtain the same information, but on a monthly basis, instead of just current date.
For instance for every month in 2021 and 2022, identify the number of unique Ids which, by the end of each month, did not have an event in the last 7 days. I am struggling to understand how to do this calculation for every month in these two years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we generate some data in table `tbl`.

We need to check an certain times (1st of month for last month). These combination are created in table `all_combinations`. The dates are tuncated to the first of the month and a month is added, because the check of the last month is done on the 1st of the next one.

Both the `tbl` and the `all_combinations` are combined (`union all`) and marked by the `test` column.

I commented out two helper lines in the main `SELECT`. The check is done on the 1st of the month for the last one and thus we calculate the `date_check` by substracting one day.

The window function `last_date_window` looks for the last date of the `id` (`partition by`). The `lag` function does not work, because we need to exclude the test dates with an `if` statement, the `last_value` function is used.

We substract the date from the previous date. If the difference is null, because it is the first entry, we set it to 99 days. If the difference is greater than 7 days the `qualify` will keep that record.

```sql
with tbl as 
(Select cast(rand()*10 as int64) Id,  date,"E" event from unnest(generate_date_array("2021-01-01","2022-09-23",interval 1 day)) as date),
all_combinations as 
(Select *, "" event, true test 
  from (Select distinct id from tbl) 
  cross join (Select distinct date_add(date_trunc(date,month),interval 1 month) as date from tbl))
select *,
#last_value(if(test,null,date) ignore nulls) over (last_date_window  ) as last_date,
#ifnull(date_diff(date, last_value(date) over last_date_window,day),99) as diff,
date_sub(date,interval 1 day) as date_check
 from (select *, false as test from tbl union all select * from all_combinations)

qualify 
  ifnull(date_diff(date, last_value(date) over last_date_window,day),99)  >7+1 and test
 window
  last_date_window as (partition by id order by date,test desc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)

 
order  by date,test desc
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, thank you for your reply. However, your answer is confusing, can you please explain it a bit better? Also, by looking at the code I see there are references to a last_date_window, but this is not defined in the code?

Comment: @msc01 the `last_date_window` is defined in the 2nd last row. It is a `window` function and I explained that it does, the basis are in the [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls). To answer your questions advanced SQL knowledge is needed, such a window function. I build a query, which can run on its own, without any further data. Please give it a try and run it in BigQuery. Please comment out the `qualify 
  ifnull(` ... for testing.

Comment: apologies from my previous comment. I erroneously copied the code without the part after qualify. I have thoroughly tested your solution and it is indeed what I was looking for. My suggestion for better legibility would be to break down the explanation of the solution in the different steps - due to my lack of deep expertise in SQL, I ended up doing that to explain it to myself, since I was not understanding the reason of the lines 'last_value...; ifnull...; date_sub...' in the main select. Many thanks!